# Big O notation for exponential and logarithmic complexity

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

There are a lot of questions about big O notation, but I didn't found clear answer for this question.

We write that:
O(5n) = O(n)
and
O(3n^2 + n + 2) = O(n^2)

Can we write that:
O(2^(2n)) = O(2^n)?

The same for logarithmic complexity:
O(n log(4n)) = O(n log(n))?

Comment: Give this chapter a read http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap0.pdf.

Comment: O(2^(2n)) = O(2^2 + 2^n) = O(4 + 2^n) = Constant + O(2^n) = O(2^n)

Comment: @jernej `2^2n` is not `2^2 + 2^n`. It's `2^n * 2^n`

Comment: typo, but result is the same.

Comment: @jerney The result is not the same. See my answer.

Comment: 2^n * 2^n = 2^(n+n) = 2^2n so the're the same. But it'll be better to write: 2^2n = (2^2)^n = (2^n)^2 :)

Comment: this should be on cstheory, but no reason to downvote imho

Comment: this question belong on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or other but not on stack

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only constants you can remove are additive and multiplicative ones. Meaning O(f(*n*)) = O(f(*n*) + C) = O(C × f(*n*)).

2<sup>2*n*</sup> = (2<sup>*n*</sup>)<sup>2</sup>. This 2 constant cannot be ignored as it is an exponent. Just as O(*n*) and O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) are different complexity classes, so are O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) and O(2<sup>2*n*</sup>).

On the other hand, yes, O(*n* log 4*n*) = O(*n* log *n*). We can use a logarithmic identity to turn the 4 into an multiplicative constant: O(*n* log 4*n*) = O(*n* (log *n* + log 4)) = O(*n* log *n* + (log 4) *n*) = O(*n* log *n* + *n*) = O(*n* log *n*).